# Converting output of cv2.mean() to other color models (LAB)

Tags: python, opencv, mean

Using OpenCV 2 (3.1.0) and python 2.7 If you pass a image or video frame to `cv2.mean()` you get an output like

```
(57.679779052734375, 70.36699761284721, 102.41968960232204, 0.0)
```

1. Does the returned value follow the OpenCV convention of BGR (not
   RGB) and what does the last value mean?
2. If I wished to translate the value returned to L*A*B color model
   what is the best way of doing so without recalculating the mean?

I've tried using colormath module to convert from rgb to xyz to lab but if I use manual online colour converters the input(RGB) doesn't look like the same colour when converted to LAB and the inputI start with isn't what I was expecting as the mean of the source image/frame

```
    from colormath.color_objects import XYZColor, sRGBColor,LabColor
    from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
    #RGB-Blue   RGB-Green   RGB-Red
    #57.6797790527  70.3669976128   102.4196896023

    #BGR
    #107    127 133


    rgb = sRGBColor(133, 127, 107)
    xyz = convert_color(rgb, XYZColor, target_illuminant='d50')
    lab = convert_color(xyz,LabColor)
```

Comment: It calculates mean for each channel independently. The result contains one mean per channel, in the same order (wouldn't really make sense otherwise). What the particular channels represent is irrelevant to that function. | If the result has 4 values, then you passed it a 4 channel image - something with transparency. You can easily verify that by inspecting the `shape` attribute of the input array.

Comment: I'm my case it's a frame from a video accessed via cv2.VideoCapture and read()

Answer (score 3):

So OpenCV has its own convention for the range of values for different color spaces, which in turn is dependent on the type of image you use. For example, CV_64 has different conversion equations than CV_32 and CV_16 and so on.

For an example:(*Technically, if you did some homework on the documentation you would understand it from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor))*

If [R,G,B] = [220, 233, 119] and you go to [this website](http://colormine.org/color-converter) and convert it

the Lab values would be

[L, a, b] = [89.31, -20.33, 53.44]

Now, in OpenCV, for the type CV_32FC3, the Lab conversion would be as follows:

`[R, G, B][220, 233, 119] = CV[L, a, b][2.55 * 89.31, 128 + (-20.33), 128 + 53.44]`

**Note** - Important to check the type of the image when using the convention.

*Alternatively, if you have the motivation, why don't you create images with all channels with the same value, convert them using* `Imgproc.cvtcolor` *to whatever color space you want and then come up with the formula? That's how I did it. The confusion after this was solved with the documentation when I changed the image types.*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for joining in. Maybe some extra background will help. I'm not interested in converting frame X or Y to another colour model. I'm taking the mean of individual frames to build up a dataset to give a representation of a video as 1 image. I set the height but each pixel along the width represents a frame and is coloured by its mean. I'll to apply k-means to cluster the LAB colour to see if I can see segments of the original video using just colour. I'd prefer not to create mulitple images and just convert from RGB to lab where the euclidean distance can be used to cluster

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a video, you scan it frame by frame (RGB) calculate its mean and save it as Lab. Then with these values, you classify using k-means. I don't really understand where the problem is, looks to me it is straight forward.

Comment: Yip easy to say but stumbling to do the conversion without needing to create a interim image just to convert it to lab

Comment: With this formula, you don't need to

Comment: Hi Rick, I don't follow where you found the formula to go from rgb values to lab, can you link to the code or explaination for the values?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor)